# ArrayList Serialization with Multiple Instances/Extends

Tags: java, arraylist

Lets say I have an ArrayList that contains instances of multiple classes that extends from the "People"(Lets call it that) class.

An example:
Example two Strings are Name and Course Name

```
ArrayList<People> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(new Teacher("Mrs. Doe","Math"));
people.add(new Student("Bob","Math"));
people.add(new Student("Sue","Math"));
people.add(new Student("Joe","Math"));
```

Quick example of the structure of these classes:

```
 abstract class People implements Serializable
    {
        String name;
        String course;
        ...
        private People(String newName, String newCourse)
        {
            this.name = newName;
            ...
        }
        @Override
        public String toString(){return...}
    }
    public class Teacher extends People
    {
        public class Teacher... yada-yada{
        super(variables)}
        @Override String toString(){return...}...
    }
    public class Student extends People
    {
        public class Teacher... yada-yada{
        super(variables)}
        @Override String toString(){return...}...
    }
```

**Is it possible to output the ArrayList to a file without getting any errors(hehe)?**

Error: `java.io.NotSerializableException: mvc.Model`

It yells at me for this line: `out.writeObject(people);`

Is that not allowed? Is life not this easy? Could these extra instances be interfering with this?
I've done some quick dirty code with making a new list without any extra instances and it worked.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried writing the array list without the toString. You could serialize the class, then write the ArrayList, just as you would write any other object.

**Writing the ArrayList:**

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(ARRAY_NAME);
```

Just remember to include the following to decode the serialization:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 123456;
```

**Reading the ArrayList:**
When trying to read the ArrayList back in, you could do this: (as long as it is from the same serialized class)

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    ARRAY_NAME = (ARRAY_TYPE_CAST)ois.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to output the ArrayList to a file without getting any errors(hehe)?**

Extend `Arraylist` and implement `java.io.Serializable` like this -

```
public class MyList extends ArrayList implements java.io.Serializable
```

For you to serialize an object you need to extend `java.io.Serializable`. Since you need to serialize `ArrayList`, simply extend it.

PS - Keeping your question simple would get you more help.